# Accessing a string within a list of classes

Tags: c#, list, class, listbox

I have a class named 'Advisers' which contain a list of students advised named 'Students Advised'. What I want to do is display the list of students advised of one instance of the adviser class in a listbox. Basically I want to isolate the strings 'FirstName' and 'LastName' which are components of the 'Student' class in the list 'StudentsAdvised'.

I've tried using .datasource to populate the listbox but it just displays the name of the namespace.

This is what I have:

```
private void adviShowInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = adviListBox.SelectedIndex;

        advInfoDisplayFirst.Text = AdviserList[index].FirstName;
        advInfoDisplayLast.Text = AdviserList[index].LastName;
        advInfoDisplayDep.Text = AdviserList[index].Department;

        advInfoStudentBox.DataSource = AdviserList[index].StudentsAdvised;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following :

```
private void adviShowInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = adviListBox.SelectedIndex;

    advInfoDisplayFirst.Text = AdviserList[index].FirstName;
    advInfoDisplayLast.Text = AdviserList[index].LastName;
    advInfoDisplayDep.Text = AdviserList[index].Department;

    //this will traverse your StudentsAdvised list
    foreach (Advisers a in AdviserList[index].StudentsAdvised)
    { 
         advInfoStudentBox.Items.AddItem(a.LastName + ", " + a.FirstName);
    }

}
```

Comment: No problem, hope it goes well!